# How to do line break in mermaid sequence diagram md file?

Tags: mermaid

I have a long line in sequence diagram.

```
sequenceDiagram
    Alice -> Bob: Loooooooooooooooooooooong Text
```

instead, I want to line break like below

```
sequenceDiagram
    Alice -> Bob: | 
    Loooooooooooooooooooooong 
    Text
```

or

```
sequenceDiagram
    Alice -> Bob: "Loooooooooooooooooooooong 
    Text"
```

how do I line break in mermaid md file?

I searched stackoverflow but `<br>` is for line break in the output graph.

Comment: This is about breaking the source code, not rendering a line break in the generated diagram, right?

Comment: related?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77364261/how-to-do-line-break-in-mermaid-sequence-diagram-md-file/77759903#77759903